# How to report failures in command line app being run in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

So we are running a command line app as part of the build but when there is an exception that causes the command line tool not to run correctly the build still flags that step as passed. Is there a way to report back to the build there as an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the envelopment variable %ERRORLEVEL% after you run the command